# Isolate scope in Angularjs custom directives - "="

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a simple directive for a test app I'm making.  My directive is as follows:

```
  .directive('answer', function(){
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: {
        minl: "=",
        model: "="
      },
      template: '<input id="option" name="opts" type="text" ng-model="model" ng-minlength="minl">'
}
```

})

In my html file I'm using this directive with the following code:

```
<answer ng-repeat="option in newQuestion.opts" minl="minLength" model="option.value"></answer>
```

I have a minLength property on my controller scope (equal to 10) and option.value has a value on the scope as well.  However, my template does not pull in either of these values when I load the html page.  Does anybody have any advice on what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: this worked when I used minl: "@" rather than "=", but ng-minLength is still not pulling in the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have minLength declared as an int on the controller ( NOT Directive's controller ) your code is perfectly written Angular.

I've created it again on plunkr, so you can look, I didn't change anything beside declaring the minLength value on the Controller. **[Plunk, Please notice that I called it on my end minl at the controller. thats the only difference](http://plnkr.co/edit/wKYzMqruaiWWNiJPfS8C?p=preview)**

```
  scope: {
    minl: "=",
    model: "="
  }
```

Is the way to go.

Comment: Ofc look at the Inspect Element to see that ng-minlength is 10. And becomes valid when you type more than 10.

Comment: weird. i can see clearly that this is working, but it doesn't work when i do it myself...

Comment: Try debugging your own code. make sure that the value on the controller is defined. Also, first try without ng-repeat, then try with it. Move forward slowly & carefully.

Comment: I guess nothing is binding to the template, but I don't know why. Even when i use the @ and define minl as 10 in the html attribute....

Comment: Ok, we can debug it as well. Copy Paste into a plunk ? the controller, directive, and html?

Comment: It started working once I started using Angular 1.3 (rather than 1.2.19), so it seems like some capability they added to the ng-minlength directive.  I'm looking into the updates they made now to see why that is

Comment: I can see what you are referring, testing the own code didn't work with 1.2.2 But as far as I'm concerned they haven't pushed anything different on ng-minlength at 1.3. could be something with directives

Answer (score 0):

Write your directive scope allocations like this:

```
       scope: {
         minl: "=myMinl",
         model: "=myModel"
  }
```

then in your markup do this:

```
<answer ng-repeat="option in newQuestion.opts" myMinl="minLength" myModel="option.value"></answer>
```

Comment: nope, ng-minLength still evaluates to minl when I do that.

Comment: Right, its supposed to evaluate to minl. because you are assigning myMinl to minl.